# Filter dataset value in Textbox based on other dataset

Tags: reporting-services, report, rdlc, ssrs-2012

I have two datasets, one that returns summary data of employee and one that returns more of statistics data.

[image]

I am trying to create SSRS report where the Dataset1 data gets displayed in the grid and Dataset2 data get displayed outside the grid. I am able to display grid data separately in different page for each employee by using page break in parent group by EmployeeId in the grid. Now i am trying to figure out how to display employee statistics data outside the grid from DataSet2 that matches with employee summary data in grid in each page. I am not sure if this can be done without using subreport but trying not to use it.

**Report Mockup:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should have one table with two row groups involved here. Lets's say Group1 is by employee ID and then inside that, Group2 by Date. Group1 should have a page break between instances. In your table, you should have rows below Group2 but still inside Group1. This way, they repeat once per employee, but not by date. These rows can be formatted without borders so that they appear to be outside the "grid". And the counts will naturally aggregate over each emplyee's records.

Your table should look something like this:

[image]